# How to run Keycloak as a docker container in production

Tags: docker, keycloak

Im fairly new to docker and can't get Keycloak running in production. I followed every step on: https://www.keycloak.org/server/containers#_building_your_optimized_keycloak_docker_image
but still it isn't running for me. Can somebody pls help?

I did setup a mysql container as follow:
docker run -p 3306:3306 --name mysql -d --net keycloak-network -e MYSQL_DATABASE=keycloak -e MYSQL_USER=keycloak -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root mysql

I also put both containers in a docker network and did build the Keycloak dockerfile just like the Keycloak doc but I get an Error telling me:

Failed to obtain JDBC connection

my dockerfile looks like this:

[image]

Can't get Keycloak running in production

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.